# DATEDIFF displaying null values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have used DATEDIFF to distinguish  between when the first unit rate was created and the posting date is when the first transaction of that item was posted. 
I have the result that I need , however the DateDiff function gives me NULL values starting date for some rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.[Entry No_] ,
            a.[Starting Date],
            b.[Posting Date], 
            b.[Item No_],  
            b.[Invoiced Quantity],  
            a.[Litre Conversion Factor], 
            a.[Unit Rate] , 
            b.[Location Code],  
            a.[Excise Location], 
            a.[Excise Type Code], 
            a.[Unit Of Measure Code]                
FROM [Spier Live$Value Entry] b 

LEFT JOIN [Transfer Excise Tbl] a 

 ON a.[No_] = b.[Item No_]
  AND b.[Location Code] = a.[Location Code]
  AND DateDiff(y,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) > -365 --DateDiff Year -365 for starting date
 AND DateDiff(y,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) < 0    --DateDiff Yer < 0 for posting date
 WHERE b.[Posting Date] > '2013-02-26'                     --This is when the unit rate was entered
 AND b.[Gen_ Bus_ Posting Group] IN ('LOCA','EXSA')
 AND b.[Invoiced Quantity] <>0                             --Removing all zero values 
 AND b.[Item No_] = 'F00335' 
 ORDER BY b.[Posting Date]
```

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxjuO.jpg)

[Transfer Excise Tbl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HYpJ.jpg) This is the table I am joining on

Comment: which date difference are you using? ...years or days

Comment: If any of your dates are `null` in such cases, this is totally correct behaviour. What else could it show? @alex It says which right there.

Comment: @alex , I am using years

Comment: @underscore_d, there cannot be Null dates because my erp system displays dates for all items

Comment: If any of the conditions in your `left join` are false, you will see `null`s for any columns from table `a`.

Comment: Anyway, post sample data, desired output, and actual output. Otherwise there is little point in anyone speculating.

Comment: @Underscore_d, table a does not contain null values

Comment: @user2941071 but if the `left join` criteria fail, it will _seem to_. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Underscore_d, I already have my desired/actual output which is correct , I want to know whey does the DateDiff display null values for certain starting dates

Comment: So the desired output is what you actually get? What's the problem then? What do you mean 'the `datediff` displays'? You're never returning the results of any `datediff` for viewing. The only thing it affects are whether columns from table `a` are `left join`ed. So you must be seeing the `null`s somewhere else. Where? Post more info. We're not psychic.

Comment: sorry,are you sure about using dayofyear ?

Comment: The starting date is for a year for a given unit rate for an item , for the entire year , the starting date for that item will be the same , If I entered a unit rate for an item on the 2015-02-26 , that date will be for a year , how can the datediff give values for certain rows and not for other , its not possible , because the starting date must reflect for the item

Comment: DateDiff(y,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) > -365  y is dayofyear

Answer (score 0):

As **alex** points out in the comments, you're looking for things with `datediff`s based on *day of year*, not year. Did you mean `<= 0`, btw? These criteria don't make sense and so probably aren't what you really want. If so, they'd cause `join`s to fail where you don't really want them to, leading to `null`s showing for table `a` columns.

Comment: I have attached my result , that is the result I need but I have nulls

Comment: I did not try fixing my date diffs , Yes I need to filter on items less that - 365 because that is how our ERP system works

Comment: What is the best way to remove the nulls and display the correct data

Comment: The best way to fix your problem is to attempt solutions people offer and tell them whether they work. Or make sure you're asking the right thing in the first place. Confirm: Do you want to filter on **years** or **days**? If days, then fix your query, and tell us what _that_ does. If you really do want to filter on years - which seems wrong based on the presence of `-365` - then your query is working perfectly, and you, again, need to be more clear about what you want in such situations instead of `null`s. You can't just "remove the nulls"; seeing as they themselves represent absence of data.

Comment: Oops, **alex** is right: `y` means 'day of year', _not_ year. Here's why I always type the full unit in `datediff` rather than arcane abbreviations. Still, the ultimate result is the same: a nonsensical `join` condition

Comment: I have changed my query to days , still gets Nulls , I tried less than 365 and greater than 0 still gets nulls and some duplicates

Comment: Oops, I should've said _greater than_ 365 and _less than_ or equal to 0. Is that what you did?

Comment: I have attached the table structure I am joining on

Comment: AND DateDiff(y,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) > 365 
AND DateDiff(y,b.[Posting Date],a.[Starting Date]) >= 0 
 ,this is what I did I get nulls and also duplicates

Comment: Sorry, y DATEDIFF is dayofyear, yuo can use yy for year and dd for day

Comment: @underscore_d, sorry you were correct , my data is correct